# making a view move from one coordinate to another coordinate in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, imageview

I have an image view and a photoview in android studio. The photoview is set to an image bitmap. I want to initially place a view on a specific x, y coordinate on top of the photoview but I want to place the view depending on the matrix of the image bitmap, not the photoview. Then I want to make the image view translate from 1 x, y coordinate to another coordinate. what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague but looking at the title of the question, to move a view to the coordinates of another view, you could set the x and y to the values of the view you want to move to. Let's say you want to move imagview1 to the point where imageview2 is:

`imageview1.animate().x(imageview2.getX()).y(imageview2.getY());`

Or if you don't wanna animate it just remove animate():

````
imageview1.setX(imageview2.getX());```

Could you elaborate more or in this case, clearly
````